# Spot pops after wudu

Tags: salat, wudu, taharah

Salam, I have acne on my face and after doing wudu some spots burst. Today I was doing wudu and when drying I avoided the spot but it burst and I wasn’t sure whether my wudu was valid so I waited and wiped away the pus and blood. After that another one burst whilst doing wudu and I got fed up so I tried washing out the blood and only a very small amount was on the surface of it but it was dripping down. Is my wudu valid?

Comment: The prophet didn't renew ablution after a single point cupping, recorded by muhaddith darukatni. In cupping blood flows from cut.

Comment: So my wudu is still valid? Because it’s annoying when it happens and I can’t always prevent them popping even when I’m extremely careful

Comment: As per shaafae, hambali, salafi and shia pus and blood other than from 2 excrement openings doesnt invalidate Ablution

Comment: @Abdurrehman Salafi isn't a fiqh school of thought It's an aqeeda/madhab school of thought, sufis also follow shaafae, hanbali, and maliki, and hanafi fiqhs. Also, there are 2 major different fiqhs in shia and you just stated "shias" please tell the different opinions of both of them and the sunni hanafi fiqh as well. Also, add some evidence to your claims like Quran, Hadith, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Salam,
In my opinion, your wudu is valid. Remember Allah (swt) made wudu simple for us, and we aren't supposed to feel frustrated doing it. Some of the scholars said that if water (pus) from wounds is a small amount, it does not invalidate wudoo, but if it is a large amount then it does invalidate wudoo’.
Hope that helps.
MuslimGap

Comment: This helps, jazakallah khair.